# Positioning a div element created with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position

I have a jQuery function to create a simple div, code follows -
`var mouseX;` `var mouseY;`

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
  mouseX = e.pageX;
  mouseY = e.pageY;
});

function createObj() {
  var o = $('<div />');
  o.addClass('myDiv');
  o.css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('slow');
  $(document.body).append(o);
}
```

My problem is that the first div is created at the requested location, but if I call the function again to create another div it is created below the first div and the next one is create below the second etc.

How can I make the new div at the current mouse location?

Comment: are they defined as `absolute`? can you make a fiddle?

Comment: your code is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fy7x5vmr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is doing what you want it to do, you just can't tell whether the divs are on top or under each other because they have the same color.

This code creates a random color for each new div so you can see that the new ones are actually on top of the old ones:

```
var colors = ["blue", "red", "lime", "purple"];
color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];

$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
  mouseX = e.pageX;
  mouseY = e.pageY;
});

function createObj() {
  var o = $('<div />');
  o.addClass('myDiv');
  o.css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX, background: color}).fadeIn('slow');
  $(document.body).append(o);
  color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
}
$(document).click(createObj);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/jsbrown/pen/13233d9ab9d4fe2b5d54f37b8d2720ae?editors=001)

Comment: Thanks James,
If I make o draggable then it does not create the object at the mouse location position, is there a solution for that ?

Comment: Hi again,
I found that if I set the position of the div AFTER I add it to the document body it works fine.
Thank you